# Add files to User Data Path in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, publish, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

In previous version of Visual Studio if I've needed to put files in a Users Data Path, I have created a Separate Setup Project application - where you could specify where a program should be loaded, whether to put shortcuts on the desktop and add any data to the User's Data Path.

I can't seem to find how I add a setup program in Visual Studio 2017.

To that end how would I add User specific data when I publish an application in Visual Studio 2017 - assuming the setup program type is now redundant. If it is not redundant - where can I find it?

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installer projects are a separate add-in from the Visual Studio Marketplace site:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects